# Trying to change the range of the random number based on the difficult the user chooses

Tags: python

```
import random, math

tries = 0
extreme = 5000000
hard = 5000
medium = 1000
easy = 250
beginner = 100

print("Welcome to the number guessing game!")
print("Choose a difficulty: extreme, hard, medium, easy, beginner")
difficult = raw_input()
```

I'm getting the error here on the 14th line.
The error is: "

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Programing/Learning/Python/guessGame.py", line 14, in <module>
    answer = random.randint(1, int(difficult))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'easy'
```

"
I have changed it a to everything I thought would work to no avail.

```
answer = random.randint(1, int(difficult))
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 1):

You cant use user entered strings to directly map with variables. You should use a dictionary for such case. Hope this helps -

```
import random, math

tries = 0
level_dict = {
    'extreme' : 5000000,
    'hard' : 5000,
    'medium' : 1000,
    'easy' : 250,
    'beginner' : 100
}

print("Welcome to the number guessing game!")
print("Choose a difficulty: extreme, hard, medium, easy, beginner")
difficult = raw_input()
answer = random.randint(1, level_dict[difficult])
```

Comment: Thanks @nu11p01n73R, I was in a hurry,

Comment: Thanks I understood that you meant but it into a dictionary I added a Vikas over 9000 setting. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this and look up the values from a dictionary:

```
difficulties = {
    'extreme': 5000000,
    'hard': 5000,
    'medium': 1000,
    'easy': 250,
    'beginner': 100
}

print("Choose a difficulty: extreme, hard, medium, easy, beginner")
difficulty = raw_input()

if difficulty in difficulties:
    maxRange = difficulties[difficulty]
    answer = random.randint(1, maxRange)

    # …
else:
    print('Invalid difficulty')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to convert 'easy' string into an integer number, which as seen in the compiler messages doesn't work. Proper way would be to change difficult depending on what you get so, a short workaround would be to create a dictionary instead of hard coded variable names

```
difficulty_dict = {}
difficulty_dict['extreme'] = 5000000
difficulty_dict['hard'] = 5000
difficulty_dict['medium'] = 1000
difficulty_dict['easy'] = 250
difficulty_dict['beginner'] = 100

difficult = raw_input()
answer = random.randint(1, difficulty_dict[difficult])
```